# How do I calculate how many X requests were open as of each date?

Tags: sql

Using 
https://data.seattle.gov/Public-Safety/PDRs-After-using-City-of-Seattle-Public-Records-Re/wj44-r6br/data I want the know on each date the number of public disclosure requests were open. This means per date I want the number of requests created before or same day as date and don't have a close date after the date.

I copied it to https://data.world/timacbackup/seattle-police-public-disclosure-requests where I can use SQL.

The closest I've gotten is

```
SELECT CAST(seattle_police_records_requests.request_create_date AS DATE) AS the_date,
    count(*)
FROM seattle_police_records_requests
GROUP BY CAST(seattle_police_records_requests.request_create_date AS DATE)
ORDER BY the_date DESC;
```

I tried

```
SELECT CAST(request_create_date AS DATE) AS the_date,
    count((
            SELECT request_create_date
            FROM seattle_police_records_requests AS t
            WHERE CAST(t.request_create_date AS DATE) < d.request_create_date
            ))
FROM seattle_police_records_requests AS d
GROUP BY CAST(request_create_date AS DATE)
ORDER BY the_date DESC;
```

but get unknown table 'd' for the count subquery.

The last query I tried is

```
WITH dates
AS (
    SELECT CAST(request_create_date AS DATE) AS create_date,
        CAST(request_closed_date AS DATE) AS closed_date
    FROM seattle_police_records_requests
    ),
create_dates
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT CAST(request_create_date AS DATE) AS create_date
    FROM seattle_police_records_requests
    )
SELECT create_dates.create_date,
    COUNT(*)
FROM dates
INNER JOIN create_dates ON dates.create_date = create_dates.create_date
GROUP BY create_dates.create_date
HAVING dates.create_date <= create_dates.create_date
ORDER BY create_dates.create_date DESC
```

and basically it's just counting # of requested opened on given day not all that were open as of given day.

Comment: Tag  your question with the database you are using and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Your first query looks pretty close to what you're after. Does that one give you an error? ... no results? ...?

Comment: seems 'd' is unknown because you are specified the use of 'd' outside of SELECT subquery. You are using 'd' in your subquery while you have specified 'd' in your main query.

Comment: The first one is what I would have gone for, what is wrong with it?

Comment: @GordThompson I per date I want the number of requests created before or same day as date and don't have a close date after the date.

Comment: @SimonBerthiaume per date I want the number of requests created before or same day as date and don't have a close date after the date

Comment: *"don't have a close date after the date"* - In other words, `request_close_date IS NULL` ...?

Comment: @GordThompson no it could after the given date we're looking at and therefore be open but not open a day after it closes.

Comment: So you want a count `WHERE request_create_date <= given_date AND (request_close_date > given_date OR request_close_date IS NULL)` ?

Comment: @GordThompson I'm struggling with how to turn this into a full query where does given_date come from for example

Comment: For a specific `given_date` you could just replace `given_date` with the desired date value. For a range of `given_date` values you could use a separate "dates table" covering the range of dates you're interested in, or possibly CTE (Common Table Expression), depending on the dialect of SQL you will use. (That's why the first commenter asked which database (and therefore, SQL dialect) you're using.)

Comment: @GordThompson thank you for all the help. I still haven't figured it out, see latest sql I've tried.

Comment: So your latest `WITH ...` query does not throw any errors and simply gives results other than what you desire. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After importing the "created" and "closed" values into SQL Server as `datetime` columns I was able to generate the counts per day like so:

```sql
WITH 
given_dates AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CAST(created AS DATE) AS given_date 
    FROM seattle_police_records_requests
)
SELECT 
    given_date, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM seattle_police_records_requests
        WHERE created <= DATEADD(DAY, 1, given_date) AND (closed > given_date OR closed IS NULL)
    ) AS num_open
FROM given_dates
ORDER BY given_date;
```

The `DATEADD` was necessary to include requests opened during that day, since the comparison of a `date` and a `datetime` implies that the `date` value is midnight (i.e., the very beginning of that day).